# How to exclude a certain filetype from showing in problems by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to exclude a certain file type (or more than one) from showing in `Problems`? I can exclude problems caused by `*.dtpl` files with `!*.dtpl` in the `Problems` filter; how can I make this a default, avoiding to put it in each time anew?

Aside: I could not find a comprehensive explanation how the filer for `Problems` work. Any hint?

I use:
Version: 1.81.1
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:18:39.991Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.1.0-11-amd64

Comment: if the doc pages do not give enough explanation you can create an issue on the vscode doc repo for that particular page

Comment: I know how to filer the currently shown problems. The question is, perhaps not worded clearly enough, how to make a setting default (i.e. permanent for a while) so it is not necessary to put in in again and again after each restart. I expected that there is some "setting", but could not find it.